# Disable biometry authentication on demand

Tags: android, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric, biometricmanager

I am trying to implement user-defined app locking mechanism with the help of BiometricManager. The app's config has a toggle which allows users to either enable or disable app lock. Once enabled, I want to use new [biometric API](https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth). This part looks pretty straightforward to me, but I can not find any information about how to reset or disable the biometry settings for an app. This is how I do trigger biometry configuration being setup:

```
private val enableLock = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
   if (it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
       val value = it.data?.getStringExtra("input")
   }
}
...
val enrollIntent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_BIOMETRIC_ENROLL).apply {
  putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_BIOMETRIC_AUTHENTICATORS_ALLOWED, authentications)
}
enableLock.launch(enrollIntent)
```

But once this method called on a preconfigured biometry, the resultCode is always `RESULT_CANCEL`, meaning API itself doesn't allow re-configuration. Any ideas?